# Como obter o número de série (não o IMEI) de dispositivos iOS e Android?

Tags: android, delphi, ios, firemonkey

Como obter o número serial de um dispositivo móvel?

Preciso da solução em delphi, firemonkey que funcione tanto em Android quanto no iOS.

Comment: Acredito que não exista algo deste tipo, no iOS antigamente existia o UDID que se não me engano a Apple não permite mais que ele seja usado, já no Android desconheço qualquer coisa deste tipo, e muito menos algo que funcionasse igual nos dois, que no caso teria que ser algo próprio do FireMonkey que abstraísse o recurso do sistema operacional, e no geral algo que possa identificar unicamente qualquer aparelho é muito mal visto pelos usuários

Comment: No iOS, se está se referindo ao UDID do dispositivo, não há como você pegar o UDID, há algumas maneiras que ele "gera" uma espécie de UDID mas que não é o real. Como exemplo, basta baixar um app da apple store para capturar o mesmo.

Answer (score 1):

Solução para o Android.

Em Delphi não tenho ideia, mas você pode procurar as classes nativas do android, como se fosse no Java (creio eu) e tentar fazer algo parecido.

No java:

```
android.telephony.TelephonyManager.getDeviceId()
```

Este trecho de código vai retornar uma string com a identificação do dispositivo (IMEI no GSM e MEID no CDMA).

Pra que isso funcione, é necessário utilizar a permissão:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Para mais detalhes, clique [aqui](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getDeviceId%28%29)!

Comment: Obrigado pela dica vou verificar. Na verdade o que eu preciso e criptografar uma informação e adicioná-la a um arquivo INI. (essa rotina já está pronta e funcionando parcialmente). O arquivo será usado para autenticar o usuário sem que ele tenha que informar login e senha sempre for entrar no app. Eu gostaria de criptografar está informação usando o id do dispositivo como parte da chave, evitando assim que o arquivo INI seja copiado para outro dispositivo liberando o acesso. A minha maior dificuldade é obter esse ID do dipositivo.

Comment: Device ID e IMEI são coisas distintas.

Comment: Usar o MAC Address não seria uma alternativa nesse caso?

Answer (score 1):

Adicione Androidapi.JNI.Os e use a seguinte função:

```
JStringToString(TJBuild.JavaClass.SERIAL);
```

Answer (score 0):

**getDeviceId()**

> Returns the unique device ID of a subscription, for example, the IMEI for GSM and the MEID for CDMA phones. Return null if device ID is not available.

Fonte: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager

Vale lembrar que esse método está **obsoleto** na API level 26.

Para pegar o IMEI, no Android, você pode tentar o método abaixo:

```
 TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)
        getSystemService(this.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        String imei = telephonyMgr.getImei();
 } else {
        String imei = telephonyMgr.getDeviceId();
 }
```

Vale lembrar que, em alguns casos, o `Device ID` pode se alterar. Diferente do IMEI, que é sempre unico.